# SQL Server to Pandas DF to Excel Error

Tags: sql-server, pandas, windows-7, sqlalchemy, xlsxwriter

We're pulling data from SQL server into a Pandas dataframe by calling a cursor via SLQAlchemy.  We're then dumping the results to excel via XlsxWriter.  For whatever reason, some records in the database that contain a comma, are displaying as a black diamond with a question mark when the pandas data frame is printed. Alternatively, when printing the row the string is displayed with '\x82'. For example:

[image: 1`]

Or

[image]

As a result, these records are erroring out when writing to the flat file.

Could someone please point me in the right direction for figuring out why this conversion issue is occuring when going from SQL Server to Pandas, and how to avoid it on a go forward?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe it is an encoding issue. utf-8 vs latin-1.

Comment: @ItayLivni thank you; currently researching may reach back out.  I'm looking into the SQL server data types and seeing if they're varchar or nvarchar and if they can be converted from UTF-8 to ASCII via encoding constraints

Comment: @llja i think it was a typo when the data was entered. it's actually a comma in the db but reading the name, and to your point, it probably should have been an apostrophe

Comment: After a little googling found the title "Who Killed John Benét", so a latin small letter e with acute.

Comment: @llja yeah, probably some ETL error.  I was just researching how to enforce ASCII compatibility on varchar column in SQL server and how to convert any non ASCII compatible data types to compatible types.  No luck yet